# JS dropdown index not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, html-select

I have a dropdown menu in Javascript I'm trying to programmatically change, but it isn't cooperating.  First of all, the text in the box remains at the first option.  If I click it to bring down the dropdown, then I see the index I've set it to is highlighted.  However, I can't select that option, but I can select any other option in the menu.  This is the code I'm using on $(document).ready:

```
document.getElementById("filteredSubDropdown").selectedIndex = localStorage["currentMonth"];
```

EDIT: some HTML where the dropdown is created

```
<div data-role="content" id="box">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="merchAccountDetails" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="firstDrop">
                <center><font size="4" color="Green" face="times new roman">Filter Data by:</font></center>
                <select id="filterByDropdown">
                </select>
            </div>
            <center><font size="4" color="Green">Filter Data by month:</font></center>
            <select id="filteredSubDropdown">
            </select>
            </center>
            <center><font size="4" color="Green">Filter Data by Account:</font><br>
            </center>
            <center>
            <select id="accountDropdown">
            </select>
            </center>
        </div>
        <div id="chicken">
            <center><img src="spin.gif" alt="loading.."/>Loading Data...</center>
        </div>
        <p id="finInfo">
        </p>
        <br/>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle a simplified version of what you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Suggestions:

1. Did you try to give a number and check if it is working?
2. What is the value of `localStorage["currentMonth"]`?

#### Try changing the code this way:

```
document.getElementById("filteredSubDropdown")
                           .selectedIndex = localStorage.getItem("currentMonth");
```

Comment: Yes, I tried a number and the same thing happens, tried your code as well.  The value in localStorage is 3.

Comment: > I tried a number and the same thing happens - @MGZero 2 mins ago

Comment: The same thing.  It highlights the index I specified when I click the dropdown, but doesn't actually change the dropdown text.

Comment: Looks like there's another underlying issue then..unfortunately, the code is proprietary and I can't really post it.

Comment: Post enough so that you can recreate the issue. I dont understand how you'd expect our help otherwise...

Comment: Hang on, I have to dig through it to find relevant code, I didn't write it.  This project is several months old and I was only brought onboard 3 weeks ago.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Praveen Kumar's answer. Otherwise, if you can use jquery,

`$("#filteredSubDropdown").attr('selectedIndex', localStorage.getItem("currentMonth"));`

Make sure you are running the javascript AFTER the element loads, so that the selector does not return null.

Also make sure that the id you are targeting is typed correctly, case sensitive.

**In addition, ensure that the select element you are targeting actually has the option you are trying to choose.**

Based on your most previous edit, it seems that you are trying to target an option that the select element does not have. Are you instead trying to add this option to the dropdown box?